# overload std::string less than operator in c++

Tags: c++, string, stl, operator-overloading

I want to use `map<string, int>` to store strings with their occurance.

due to the requirement, I have to overload the "<" operator for std::string, in a different order from the granted lexicographic order. I use a free function, as follows.

```
bool operator<(const string& a, const string& b) {
    int mini = min (a.length(), b.length());
    for(int i=0; i < mini; ++i){
        if (a[i] < b[i])
        return true;
    }
    if (a.length() <= b.length()) return false;
    return true;
}
```

however, it does not get called. the lexicographic order gets called. 
is this the right way?

Comment: This is why the ordered containers [support a custom comparator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map).

Comment: How are you creating your map? Are you telling it somehow that it should use your custom operator? Also, are you sure you want to use it _everywhere_ you may be (unknowingly) comparing strings?

Comment: yes, that is what I want to do. make the map based on my order, rather than the lexico

Comment: Note that your operator violates the strict total ordering requirement. Specifically, you have both `"a" < "bb"` and `"bb" < "a"`.

Comment: Hi, molbdnilo, no, it is strictly ordering, "a" < "bb". the difference with lexi_order is the case of "b" and "bb", which "b" > "bb"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is not the right way.

You should define a custom functor that can do the comparison that you need. Use it in creating the map.

```
struct MyCustomFunctor
{
    bool operator()(const string& a, const string& b) { /* Add the details */ }
};
```

and then, create your map using:

```
map<string, int, MyCustomFunctor> myMap;
```

If you are able to use a compiler that suppports C++11, then you can use a lambda function to do the work and not have to create a class.

```
auto lambda = [](const string& a, const string& b) -> bool {return (a < b);};
map<string, int, decltype(lambda)> myMap(lambda);
```

When you use a `map` with a custom compare function, you have to remember that the calls to `map::begin()`, `map::end()`, `map::find()`, etc. return an iterator whose type includes the custom compare function. Using `auto` is the best approach to create variables that are iterators of the `map`.

```
auto it = myMap.begin();
auto it = myMap.find("some key");
```

Comment: In modern C++, a lambda function would probably be preferable to creating a whole new class.

Comment: And that is why even in C++11 it's still easier to use function objects for template parameters